# Can I conditionally override a CSS rule using SASS?

Tags: css, sass

Say I want to define a mixin that sets the `display` property to `inline-block` **only** if it isn't already set to `block`.

Here's a hypothetical example (I realize the `unless` part isn't valid SASS; that's what I'm asking about):

```
@mixin padded
  padding: $default-padding-y $default-padding-x
  display: inline-block unless(block)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I'd assume this should leave natural block-level elements without an override on that behavior alone as well?

Comment: @Wrikken: I don't know—maybe. Seems like that would just have to be one of those decisions that involves trade-offs and gets documented. I.e., since the SASS compiler can't know in advance what *other* stylesheets have been loaded, it could either be based only on the current stylesheet or make some "sensible" guesses (e.g., div, p, h1, etc. are *probably* block).

Comment: Yes, the problem here is indeed that actual knowledge of the document would be necessary for that, which is probably a bridge to far, unless you want to end with a whole reset list of setting TAG@padded back to block. And if you already have to take that into account when adding the mixin... I'd say for this case using a nested mixin with one padded-block and one padded-inline (or whatever) could be a workable solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SASS - Manipulate inherited color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920801/sass-manipulate-inherited-color)

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would approach the situation: Take advantage of the fact that the order of your CSS properties matters. So in your mixin define display as inline-block; call it in your element; then beneath that call set the display to block, overriding the mixin.

```
@mixin padded
  padding: $default-padding-y $default-padding-x
  display: inline-block

.element
  @include padded
  display: block
```

For this very reason I usually call mixins (or extends) at the top of a ruleset.

Or, if you want to add the inline-block style dynamically, you could use JavaScript to see which display property an element has, and then apply a new class accordingly. This wouldn't need a Sass mixin.