# Use parents' property as variable with SASS

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible to use a property of a parent as variables? 
For example in this code, i'd like to be able to give the 'inner-box' element same color as its parent 'box'.

Make it something like *.inner-box {background-color: $Outer-Parent's-Color;}*

[Example on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ub6Fw/2/)

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box1">
        <div class = "inner-box">
            BOX
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box red">
    <div class="box1">
        <div class = "inner-box">
            RED BOX
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
.box {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.box1 {
    background-color: darkblue;
    padding: 10px;
}
.box.red {
    background-color: red;
}
.box.red .box1 {
    background-color: darkred;
}
.inner-box {
    background-color: $Outer-Parent's-Color;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SASS - Manipulate inherited color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920801/sass-manipulate-inherited-color)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SASS you can embed the inner box within box

```
.box {    
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: blue;

    &.inner-box {
        background-color: inherit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the inherit value:

```
.inner-box {
        background-color: inherit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Thomas Wood and @Oliver Benns: Doesn't inherit work with the parent?  It seems to me that we deal with a grandparent and a child. So nothing fancy just simple css add a selector:

```
.box {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.box, .box div div /* Selects the grandparent and child and is not a fancy sass nested selector */
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Or fancy with sass @mixin and @for and calculating the color values:

```
@mixin grandparent($h, $width: 200px) {
  width: $width;
  background-color: hsl(20 * $h, 100%, 50%);
}

@mixin child($h) {
  background-color: hsl(20 * $h, 100%, 50%);
}

@for $i from 1 through 6 {
  .box-#{$i} { @include grandparent($i, 20 * $i); }
  .box-#{$i} div div { @include child($i); }
}
```