# Make the value in parents' property as variable, so it will be usable by other properties in the children

Tags: css, sass, bourbon

[Someone asked similarly before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061927/use-parents-property-as-variable-with-sass), but my case is a bit different. I want to use the `span-columns` mixin from Bourbon. This `span-columns` produce a specific number of `padding`. I want to take that number as variable and then pass it to the child element.

So any property in the child can use `$get-from-parent`.

Here's my SASS

```
.grandparent {
    @include outer-container(100%);

    .parent {
        @include span-columns(4);
        @include omega(2);
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        @include pad (default);
        height: 500px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative; z-index:2;
    }

    .child {
        padding: $get-from-parent; /* it can be anything, not just padding */
    }
```

Which results to this as CSS,

```
.grandparent {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.grandparent .parent {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 2.3576515979%;
    width: 31.7615656014%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 2.3576515979%;
}
```

Mind the odd **2.3576515979%** number. This changes as I change the number in `span-columns`. I want to take that number as a `$get-from-parent` variable. And then use it in `margin-bottom: $get-from-parent`, `border-width: $get-from-parent`, etc.

Is it possible?

Comment: If you want the exact same percentage value to be applied for the child, [wouldn't `padding: inherit` on the child](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#value-def-inherit) suffice?

Comment: @Harry It is mainly used for padding, yes, but I plan to use it with another property. `left` or `border-width`, for example. Can it be achieved?

Comment: As you can see in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sh1o4kkg/) the inherit would work for a lot of properties. So there is a possibility that you could do this without Sass itself but I don't have a comprehensive list of properties where this would work for sure and so you'll have to try and see if it works for the props that you have in mind.

Comment: @Herry, no you misunderstood. I want to use that 2.357% not just for padding, but also for left and border-width. I want to use the parent padding's value to everything else in its children. Using `left:inherit` and `border-width:inherit` will give me nothing if the parent's left or border-width is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try figure it out by its source code:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/grid/_span-columns.scss

Trace the code:

1. The `margin` property is generate by this `@function`:
   line 86: `flex-gutter($container-columns);`
2. `$container-columns` is generate by this `@function:`
   line 55: `$container-columns: container-span($span);`

By using these two `@function`, maybe your variable can be like this:
`$get-from-parent: flex-gutter(container-span(4));`