# Automatic darken color in Sass / Compass

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I'm setting up a CSS for a website where all the links, in `:hover` state, are darker than in normal state.

I'm using Sass/Compass so I looked to the `darken` Sass method, here : http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#darken-instance_method

Here's the use : `darken($color, $amount)`

My question is : how can I make this "automatic" to set all my `<a>` elements to be 80% darker ?

What I'm trying to do is (Sass syntax) :

```
a
   background: $blue
   &:hover
      background: darken(this element background-color, 80%)
```

What's the best solution to do this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SASS - Manipulate inherited color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920801/sass-manipulate-inherited-color)

Comment: You can't have a solution for something that is impossible.

Comment: This is not possible in SASS/SCSS.  However, you could consider using the "darker" color as the link color to begin with, and set it to 80% opacity and then 100% opacity in the hover state.  Similar effect, less repetition.  The mixin you wrote hardly saves time.

Comment: Wouldn't `background: darken($blue, 80%)` work?

Comment: A dirty hack™ would be make the element sit on a black background, and change the opacity on hover

Comment: Yes that could work too I guess.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I thought about this.

The only way I found is by creating a mixin :

```
@mixin setBgColorAndHover($baseColor)
    background-color: $baseColor
    &:hover
          background-color: darken($baseColor, 5%)
```

And then :

```
.button
    +setBgColorAndHover($green) // as $green is a color variable I use.
```

Not the best, but that will do the job :)

Answer (score 23):

By now, better to use a filter in native CSS:

```
.button:hover {
  filter: brightness(85%);
}
```

Comment: It surely is a good thing to do it in plain CSS, but it doesn't answer the actual issue (set the background color and its hover background color, darkened or brightened).

Comment: Well, since you and I are the only two involved in this answer, your question was "how can I make this "automatic" to set all my <a> elements to be 80% darker ?"

https://jsfiddle.net/9emvaw10/1/

You didn't cite it had to be Sass. And, the background color is changed. If you want all links to be changed, then there's not a need for a mixin.

Comment: It wasn't clear I want to do it with Sass, and a pure CSS way to achieve that had to appear in this thread (which is 5 years old btw). However, today, for compatibility sake, I'll stick to a Sass method

Comment: Coming back to this. You're sticking with a kludge because CSS is incompatible with SASS? It seems to me adding a little CSS is cleaner for maintainability. But, TIMTOWTDI

Comment: I think what I meant is that CSS filter property browser support wasn't really great 2 years ago. As of 2021, I surely go for it, and I dropped that Sass mixin.