# Can I add to an existing property with sass?

Tags: math, properties, sass

I'm working with a media query break point and at a certain point I want to add some pixels to a handfull of elements already defined top value without having to type out each one and override them as in traditional css.

To explain further if needed I have seven elements and I am absolutely positioning along a timeline via their top property. But at a certain size I am shrinking their overall width so they stay inside the bounds of the screen with a decent amount of padding on either side (not butting up against the edges of the screen), this also changes their height which makes them look off center to the dots along the timeline that show where these occur. I want to add the same amount of extra pixels to each of these elements top value but since they all have different values normally I would have to redefine each element and manually calculate their new top value based on what they are already set to plus the amount I want to add to each.

Is there a way I can just add more pixels to the value already set?

Comment: The broad answer is "no" (though it might be possible with native CSS variables... when browser support catches up in ~5 years).  If you require help solving *this* problem, you'll need to provide actual code.

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920801/sass-manipulate-inherited-color