# SASS/Compass Math using dynamic width

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I have a container div of flexible width (90%). I would like its child div to always be 180px smaller than the parent, in terms of width.

I know this can be accomplished in JS but I'm trying to use as much CSS as possible. I have a feeling this is beyond what CSS can do, but wanted to be sure.

I want to get the width of the child (in px) and subtract 180px. Is that possible?

**Markup:**

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

**SCSS:**

```
#main {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1600px;

  .block {
    /* incorrect code: */
    width: WIDTH_OF_PARENT - 180px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920801/sass-manipulate-inherited-color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`calc` is the anwser: IE9+ : http://caniuse.com/calc

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/g2bFT/)

```
CSS

#main {
    margin:25px auto;
    width:90%;
    max-width:1200px;
    border:1px solid green;
    padding:10px;
}

.block {
    border:1px solid red;
    height:25px;
    width: calc(100% - 180px);    
}
```

**Probably advisable to use `box-sizing:border-box` to avoid confusion too.**

NB. If the inner div is to be centered then a simple 90px side margin would work too: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/g2bFT/2/

Comment: I'm guessing someone downvoted due to lack of browser support, esp in mobile browsers. This does answer the question though, plus the margin idea is an elegant solution that will work on all browsers... and thank you for the jsfiddle demos.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS calc() function has rather low support (particularly in mobile browsers).  If you want to maximize your browser support, use margins instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/CV5nb/

```
#main {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1600px;
}
.block {
    margin-left: 180px; /* or margin-left: 90px; margin-right: 90px */
}
```

Comment: `rather low support` translates as > 70% support in browsers, including ***all*** modern mobile browsers

Comment: @jumpingcode I hate to break it to you, but 70% support is not good enough and works in "all modern mobile browsers" means nothing if users aren't upgrading.  It's one thing when a browser doesn't support minor niceties like border-radius or gradients since it rarely impacts the user's ability to use the site.  When calc() support is missing, the result is almost always a spectacular failure.  Edit an answer to make technical corrections, not because you disagree with the phrasing.

Comment: I don't disagree, but your wording, to me, suggests < 33%. `Low` is a subjective measurement, but you  didn't include any facts so it's likely to mislead people is all.

Answer (score 0):

To specifically answer your question, you can use `calc`

```
-webkit-calc(100% - 180px)
-moz-calc(100% - 180px)
calc(100% - 180px)
```

However, I'd recommend you use `margin`

Answer (score 0):

Use the calc function in the css:

```
width: calc(100%-180px);
```

Comment: This would give you (90% - 180px) of 90%.

Comment: 5;Why would you use 90%?