# SASS variable value between classes

Tags: sass

I've recently started using SASS variables to write more dynamic, manageable styles. I'm wondering if it's possible to pass the value of a variable from one class to another so as to prevent writing duplicate code.

In the example below, I want all buttons to have a 3% lighten on hover. Ideally you *should* be able to set this on the ".btn" class which is applied to all buttons. You would then just need to define the value for "$btnColor" for each type of button. However, I see that it's not working as intended. The "$btnColor" variable is undefined in the lighten function.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm attempting? Do I *need* the lighten function on hover for each button class? Doesn't this seem like a waste? Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pt3ry123/5/) where you can play around with it! Thanks in advance for the input.

The markup:

```
<button class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
<button class="btn btn-secondary">Button</button>
```

The styles:

```
.btn {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    &.btn-default {
        /* Set Button Color */
        $btnColor: #192951;

        background: $btnColor;
        border: 1px solid $btnColor;
        color: #fff;
    }

    &.btn-primary {
        /* Set Button Color */
        $btnColor: #006da8;

        background: $btnColor;
        border: 1px solid $btnColor;
    }

    &.btn-secondary {
        /* Set Button Color */
        $btnColor: #5db0d8;

        background: $btnColor;
        border: 1px solid $btnColor;
        color: #fff;
    }

    &:hover {
        background: lighten( $btnColor, 3% );
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SASS - Manipulate inherited property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920801/sass-manipulate-inherited-property)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the scoping issue that I was experiencing can be resolved through the use of a mixin. Below is an example.

The markup:

```
<button class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
<button class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button>
```

The styles:

```
@mixin button($color) {
    background: $color;
    border: 1px solid $color;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    &:hover {
        background: lighten($color, 5%);
        border: 1px solid $color; 
    }
}

.btn-default {
    @include button(#192951);
    color: #fff;

    &:hover {
        color: #fff; /* Bootstrap override */
    }
}

.btn-primary {
    @include button(#006da8);
}

.btn-secondary {
    @include button(#5db0d8);
    color: #fff;

    &:hover {
        color: #fff; /* Bootstrap override */
    }
}
```