# Finding the height of multiple elements in SCSS

Tags: sass

Is there a way that I could create a variable to get the height of multiple divs? For instance $fixed-offset: .class1 + .class2; Then in my styles say margin-top: $fixed-offset + 15px;

```
$fixed-offset: .class1 + .class2;

.class {
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: $fixed-offset + 15px;
}
```

Comment: How do you think Sass knows what the height of either of those elements is?

Comment: Do these classes have their heights set in CSS?

Comment: sass is a pre-possessor, meaning pre as in before your page is actual rendered, sass only generates css, so there is no communication between sass and your page.

Comment: @cimmanon because the heights are set already but these are dynamic, they change based on device.

Comment: @MatthewRapati Yes their heights are already set in the scss doc.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920801/sass-manipulate-inherited-property

Comment: @Mark I don't require that the output communicate with the page, and as css is read sequentially this doesn't pose a problem in that this variable can be put near the end of the scss doc.

Comment: So, can you put the heights for the other 2 classes in variables and then use those variables in the other class?

Comment: Yeah thats not a problem, I guess what Im wondering is how I make that happen syntactically.