# Bulma: hover colour of links be relative to colour?

Tags: css, bulma

I am using Bulma and I wish to know if there is a way to have the hover colour of links be relative to the non-hover colour?

For example, I have the following:

```
<a class="is-primary" href="https://bbc.co.uk">BBC</a>
```

Where:

```
$bb-red: #c1282a;

// update Bulma's global variables
$primary: $bb-red;
```

And this works fine, the link shows up in that colour, but on `:hover` it goes to something that doesn't work well, on `:hover` the colour is dark grey:

[image: bulma link hover]

Is there a way to get hover link colour to be "smart" and relative to what the non-hover colour was? e.g. a lighter or darker shade of what the non-hover colour was?

Comment: Can you try the opacity property?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sass - Manipulate inherited property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920801/sass-manipulate-inherited-property)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the right way of handling it, but I did:

```
a.is-primary:hover {
    color: lighten($bb-red, 10%);
}
```

And that works, it is annoying that I have to do it for all colours and all scenarios.