# How to refer parent property within nested rule with the same name

Tags: css, less

I am trying to reuse a `background-color` definition of the parent rule set in `background-color` definition of a child rule set. However, Less evaluates the lookup as a recursion.

I would like this:

```css
.button {
  background-color: whitesmoke;

  &:hover {
    background-color: darken($background-color, 10%);
  }
}
```

to work the same way as this:

```css
@the-color: whitesmoke;

.button {
  background-color: @the-color;

  &:hover {
    background-color: darken(@the-color, 10%);
  }
}
```

but without the need for an extra variable.

The [documentation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-properties-as-variables-new-) isn't very specific on this. Am I missing something or is this just not possible?

I am aware of other solutions to changing the tint of a button on hover (e.g. using the `filter` property).

## EDIT 1:

The closest I can get to is this. I just need it to be `background-color` instead of `color`.

```css
.button {
  background-color: whitesmoke;

  &:hover {
    color: darken($background-color, 10%);
  }
}
```

The problem is the lookup of `$background-color` evaluates to the `background-color` of the same row (which, I think, doesn't ever make sense) and refuses to compile instead of evaluating to a rule in the parent rule set or just simply evaluating to one of the previous rows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sass - Manipulate inherited property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920801/sass-manipulate-inherited-property)

Comment: @disinfor No, it doesn't. Even if I overlook the CSS preprocesor difference, the linked question is concerned about the CSS `inherit` value whereas I am concerned about property value lookup.

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't cover just the `inherit` value. What you're trying to do isn't currently possible - look at what you're asking: take a previously declared property and scope it as a variable in your `hover`. Any preprocessor would have trouble with this. Would it be nice if you could do this - absolutely.

Comment: Taking a previously declared property and scoping it as a variable is kind of what property lookup does. The docs I linked explain the usage of the property lookup. The problem is what the lookup evaluates to. See EDIT 1. I still believe this is not a duplicate of that. I think I will talk to one of the Less maintainers and possibly try contributing this thing myself. I just wanted to be sure there indeed is no way to do this.

Comment: Right on! Making things better is always awesome.